# Call to php function when submit, without jQuery if possible

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, form-submit

I have a database with data about dams in it. I have one data for each dam per year. I call my database to get the dataset and it works. 
But now I would like to choose the data of one year only.

I have a function in php to connect to my database. I would like to call it when I submit my form (with the year choice).

I suppose I have to use AJAX. But my "xhr.open('GET',...)" line does not execute the function. And I don't know what to put in the addEventListener as my php returns nothing.

I do not use jQuery, so I’m searching a way to call my php function, without it, if possible.

Here is my code :

```
map.js

//AJAX pour appeler la fonction PHP connectBDD()
//envoie de la requête

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',"connexion.php?anneeSelectionnee='2016'");
xhr.send(null);

//reception des données
listAnnees = document.getElementById('annee');
if (listAnnees){
listAnnees.addEventListener('change',function(event){
  if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);  //according to  Gerars Cuadras comment
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Oui oui je suis là");
    //supprimer_ouvrages();
}
});
```

I do not show my php file "connexion.php" because it is a simple database connexion which call then javascript functions to plot dams on a map. (it was initially in a connectBDD() function in the file, but I didn't know how to call a function in AJAX and not a file).

```
index.php
  <select name="annee" id="annee">
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
```

**Other try**

I also tried without AJAX, and it worked (call the php function), however it was reload the page each time so my choice was lost .. (with connectBDD() all the code in connexion.php)

```
  <form action="index.php"> 
  <select name="annee" id="annee">
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" id="envoyer" name="envoyer" value="Changement d'années">
</form>


if (isset($_POST['envoyer'])) {
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  supprimer_ouvrages();
  </script>
  <?php
    connectBDD('2016');
}
```

I am sorry, I know it is not clear but it was to show what I tried.

**My question is :** 
How can I execute php function (or file if function is not possible) when submitting my form, without reloading the page ?

Any help would be appreciated !!

**EDIT**

"xhr.open('GET',...)" seems to be called according to my network in fact.
[image: network]

**Second edit** 
So here is my connexion.php.
I show it within a function (like in my second try), but with the ajax attempt, I just suppress the function and execute the code without function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="l93_to_wgs84.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dictionnaryFunctions.js"></script>

<?php
//script de connection à la base de données et de récupération des informations


function connectBDD($anneeSelectionnee){
  echo 'Code is executed !'

    //connexion a la base de donnees
   $host_bdd='localhost';
   $name_bdd='smthg';
   $user_bdd='smthg';
   $pass_bdd='smthg';

   try{
      $bdd = new PDO ("pgsql:host=".$host_bdd.";dbname=".$name_bdd."", "".$user_bdd."", "".$pass_bdd."") or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
      $bdd->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
      $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    }

   catch(Exeption $e){
      die("Erreur!".$e->getMessage());
   };

   //connexion réussie
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    attenteConnexion(1);
    </script>
    <?php


  // On récupère les données
  //on ne prend que les données du cours d'eau qui nous intéresse
   $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM ouvrages');

  //On affiche chaque entrée une à une
  while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
  {
    //on remplace les "_" par des espaces pour une meilleure lisibilité
    $donnees = str_replace("_"," ",$donnees);
    //coordonnees de l'ouvrage
    $latitude = $donnees['xl93'];
    $longitude = $donnees['yl93'];

    $impact = $donnees['impact'];

    //toutes les informations que l'on souhaite afficher dans la fiche d'identité
    //si on veut afficher une informations supplémentaire, c'est dans ce tableau qu'il faut ajouter une ligne
    $identite = array(
      'Nom' => $donnees['nom'],
      'ROE' => $donnees['idroe'],
      'Commune' => $donnees['commune'],
      'Syndicat' => $donnees['syndicat'],
      'Projet' => $donnees['projet'],
      'Type d\'ouvrage' => $donnees['typeouvr'],
      'Sous-type d\'ouvrage' => $donnees['sstypeouvr'],
      'Passe à poisson' => $donnees['passepoiss'],
      'Système de montaison' => $donnees['systmont'],
      'Système de dévalaison' => $donnees['systdev'],
      'Usage' => $donnees['usage'],
      'Présence d usage' => $donnees['presenceus'],
      'Etat' => $donnees['etat'],
      'Mort par dévalaison (%)' => $donnees['mortdeval'],
      'Franchissabilité à la montaison' => $donnees['franchiss'],
      'Année' => $donnees['anneemaj']);

    $courseau = $donnees['courseau'];
    $espece = $donnees['espece'];
    $annee = $donnees['anneemaj'];

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    creation_ouvrage(lambert93toWGPS('<?PHP echo $latitude;?>','<?PHP echo $longitude;?>')['latitude'],lambert93toWGPS('<?PHP echo $latitude;?>','<?PHP echo $longitude;?>')['longitude'],'<?PHP echo $impact;?>',<?PHP echo json_encode($identite);?>,'<?PHP echo $courseau;?>','<?PHP echo $espece;?>','<?PHP echo $annee;?>','<?PHP echo $anneeSelectionnee;?>');
    </script>

    <?php
  }
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  creation_liste();
  </script>
  <?php

  $reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête
  echo $anneeSelectionnee;

}
    ?>
```

If I can use 'xhr.open('GET',..)' with a PHP function instead of a php file, I would like to know the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution if someone needs :

My PHP function was returning nothing as it was calling Javacript functions directly. That was a problem for AJAX, and also quite bad as I was doing all the calculations on server side.

@Lou suggested to divide the work. Then I used my PHP function only to connect the database and return data. Then I call the javascript function I need.

With this method, my AJAX call works fine :

*javascript function that groups everything :*

```
function afficherDonnees(anneeSelectionnee){
  //on récupère les données de la table ouvrages dans la BDD
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log("connexion réussie ");
      var tableOuvrages = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      //here I do all the treatments I need on my dataset

};

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "connexion.php", true);
  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

In my PHP connexion file, I keep the connexion only :

```
   $host_bdd='something';
   $name_bdd='something';
   $user_bdd='something';
   $pass_bdd='something';

   try{
      $bdd = new PDO ("pgsql:host=".$host_bdd.";dbname=".$name_bdd."", "".$user_bdd."", "".$pass_bdd."") or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
      $bdd->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
      $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    }

   catch(Exeption $e){
      die("Erreur!".$e->getMessage());
   };


   $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM ouvrages');

   $outp = array();
   $outp = $reponse->fetchAll();
   echo json_encode($outp); //here I return my result as JSON
```

Hoping it can help someone :)